# Run an ERDAS Imagine pmdl (or bcf) via Python?

Tags: python, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing

How (or is it) possible to run an Erdas Imagine .pmdl model from a Python script?  I have successfully run .eml models but cannot get the syntax right for .pmdl

Here is what the line I want to run looks like in a BCF file:

```
modeler -nq $IMAGINE_HOME/etc/models/hpf_resolutionmerge2.pmdl -meter -state "$(ms)" "$(pan)" "$(pansharp)" 1 Unsigned_16_bit Integer Continuous useall 11 120 "None" 0.6 1 0.4 1:7 28 '$(mask.Ulx)' '$(mask.Uly)' '$(mask.Lrx)' '$(mask.Lry)' Map
```

ms, pan, pansharp, and mask are custom variables for raster files.

Alternatively, can the BCF file be launched from outside Erdas?